# Swagger OpenAPI Client Codegen issue with Polymorphism

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am trying to generate the Swagger documentation and thin client for Java from the existing controllers that we have. Following are the  sample classes:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "clazz")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Cat"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Fish.class, name = "Fish"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Frog.class, name = "Frog")
})
public interface Animal {
    String getName();
    int getType();
}
```

Here is the controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/animals")
public class AnimalController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public Animal[] getAnimalsByType(@RequestParam(required = false) String animalType) {
        AnimalType type = StringUtils.isNotBlank(animalType) ? AnimalType.valueOf(animalType) : null;
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.xyz.openapi.server.model");
        return reflections.getSubTypesOf(Animal.class).stream()
                .map(animal -> {
                    try {
                        return animal.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
                    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException |
                            NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                })
                .filter(animal -> animalType == null || type.index() == animal.getType())
                .toArray(Animal[] :: new);
    }
}
```

Here is the client code generation task from build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.3.1.RELEASE"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "5.1.0"
}
 
openApiGenerate {
        inputSpec.set("$rootDir/api-docs.json")
        outputDir.set("$rootDir/thinclient")
    
        groupId.set("com.xyz.openapi")
        id.set("openapi-thinclient")
        version.set("0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
    
        apiPackage.set("com.xyz.openapi.thinclient.api")
        invokerPackage.set("com.xyz.openapi.thinclient.invoker")
        modelPackage.set("com.xyz.openapi.thinclient.model")
    
        generatorName.set("java");
        library.set("resttemplate")
        configOptions.put("serializationLibrary", "jackson")
    }
```

When I generate client code for java using gradle openApiGenerate, I am getting the client API generated as follows

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2021-05-24T19:20:33.823042600+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]")
@Component("com.xyz.openapi.thinclient.api.AnimalControllerApi")
public class AnimalControllerApi {
    private ApiClient apiClient;

    public AnimalControllerApi() {
        this(new ApiClient());
    }

    @Autowired
    public AnimalControllerApi(ApiClient apiClient) {
        this.apiClient = apiClient;
    }

    public ApiClient getApiClient() {
        return apiClient;
    }

    public void setApiClient(ApiClient apiClient) {
        this.apiClient = apiClient;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * <p><b>200</b> - OK
     * @param animalType  (optional)
     * @return List&lt;OneOfCatFishFrog&gt;
     * @throws RestClientException if an error occurs while attempting to invoke the API
     */
    public **List<OneOfCatFishFrog>** getAnimalsByType(String animalType) throws RestClientException {
        return getAnimalsByTypeWithHttpInfo(animalType).getBody();
    }
}
```

The return type of the API is generated as `List<OneOfCatFishFrog>` instead of `List<Animal>`. Is there any change that I need to do to get this done? Please suggest!